# Rails validations: update at the same time as creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to order ActiveRecord writes to make my validations be happy, and I'm not sure what to search for this kind of problem.

The problem is that before the request would occur, everything would be valid; after the transformations would occur, everything would be valid again; but while the transformation is happening, since it's impacting more than one model instance, the database would enter an invalid state if I update each model one by one without taking into account both changes at the same time. I'd love some suggestions!

**Background**

I have a model called `HelpRequest` and another called `HelperAssignments`.

The rule is that a `HelpRequest` may have 0 or 1 **active** `HelperAssignment`s. But if a `Helper` cannot complete the request, they may reassign it to another `Helper`, creating a new `HelperAssignment`. Since we need the history of assignments to a particular `HelpRequest`, there may be a number of `HelperAssignment`s for a `HelpRequest`, but only one is active.

As a result, the `HelperAssignment` table has a few relevant attributes:

- `help_request_id`: Refers to the `HelpRequest` corresponding to this assignment.
- `close_status`: If this is set to `reassigned`, `reassignment_id` must be present.
- `reassignment_id`: For a given `help_request_id`, only one may be `nil` (i.e. it is the current active assignment)

**Problem**

When a reassignment happens...

- ... if I create the new `HelperAssignment` first, it would break validations because more than one active `HelperAssignment` for the request would be present :(
- ... if I update the old `HelperAssignment` first to have a `close_status` of `reassigned`, the new `HelperAssignment` wouldn't exist yet so I couldn't get its ID, and therefore the validations would fail.

Is there an idiomatic way to do this transformation? I'd like to avoid a) disabling validations for this particular type of requests, or b) adding an extra database state for "being in the process of reassigning". Looks like enforcing referential integrity in models can get a little tricky in Rails... thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't this kind of thing [**database transactions**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) are for?

Comment: If executing all enclosed validations are deferred to the end of a transaction... then yes! Is that the case?

Comment: No, validations are triggered on any attempt to persist an object (even if that only builds an SQL query into a transaction and does nothing yet). It only ensures that database is not in invalid state **before** these actions and **after** them.

Comment: Clarification please? So if I have a transaction and I first save the new object then modify the old one; I take the first part of your last comment to mean that each of these save events would trigger a validation, hence it's not a solution. Am I misinterpreting what you're saying? Because the second part of your comment suggests that it does validate database state only before and after the transaction but not during it, which would handle the issue.

Comment: Validaitions are app level, they affect the process of building a transaction. Transactions are lower, database level, they ensure the database "jumps" from one state to another (for all the other observers) even if that took multiple queries to do that.

Comment: have you looked at the `around_xxx` callbacks? [Active Record Callbacks](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks). You could set up an `around_create` callback and make the changes here because then you will have an id after yielding. This way the validations will pass and the assignment can occur.